# Magento 2 New Order Status remains "Processing" instead of "Pending" in custom payment method

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, order-status

I have created a custom payment method module.

System configuration has a field for selecting New order status.

Even if I set it as "Pending", new order status is showing as "processing".

Please help..

namespace/module/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

```
<system>
        <section id="payment">
            <group id="zipcodpayment" translate="label" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Zip Limited COD Payment</label>
                <field id="active" translate="label comment" sortOrder="1" type="select" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Enable</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="title" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Title</label>
                </field>
                <field id="order_status" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" canRestore="1">
                    <label>New Order Status</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Sales\Model\Config\Source\Order\Status\NewStatus</source_model>
                </field>             
                <field id="allowspecific" translate="label" type="allowspecific" sortOrder="40" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Payment from Applicable Countries</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Payment\Model\Config\Source\Allspecificcountries</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="specificcountry" translate="label" type="multiselect" sortOrder="41" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Payment from Specific Countries</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country</source_model>
                    <can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
```

Comment: which status have you selected from `Store->configuration->sales->payment method -> {your custom_method}-> new order status `?

Comment: I have selected "pending"..but still order status remains as  "processing".

Comment: check in your `store->order status` what is the `pending` and `processing`  State Code And Title.

Comment: Can you please let me know how you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 11):

In your payment method model  you can add

```
protected $_isInitializeNeeded = true;
```

In **Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment**,  you will see :

```
public function place()
{
    ....

    if ($methodInstance->isInitializeNeeded()) {
        $stateObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
        // For method initialization we have to use original config value for payment action
        $methodInstance->initialize($methodInstance->getConfigData('payment_action'), $stateObject);
        $orderState = $stateObject->getData('state') ?: $orderState;
        $orderStatus = $stateObject->getData('status') ?: $orderStatus;
        $isCustomerNotified = $stateObject->hasData('is_notified')
                    ? $stateObject->getData('is_notified')
                    : $isCustomerNotified;
    } else {
        $orderState = Order::STATE_PROCESSING;
        $this->processAction($action, $order);
        $orderState = $order->getState() ? $order->getState() : $orderState;
        $orderStatus = $order->getStatus() ? $order->getStatus() : $orderStatus;
    }

    ....
}
```

so if `$methodInstance->isInitializeNeeded()` is false  , the orderstate will be `Order::STATE_PROCESSING`;instead of what you configured in the system backend .

Comment: In my case, I also had to override 'payment_action' config, to return 'authorize_capture'... ```public function getConfigPaymentAction()
 {
  return 'authorize_capture';
 }```... on also this just saved me a few hours. thanks

Answer (score 3):

I had a [similar problem](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/180905/magento-2-new-order-status-has-no-effect-on-custom-payment-method) & I solved it by adding this method to my payment-method model:

```
/**
 * Get config payment action, do nothing if status is pending
 *
 * @return string|null
 */
public function getConfigPaymentAction()
{
    return ($this->getConfigData('order_status') == 'pending')? null : parent::getConfigPaymentAction();
}
```

**Taken from \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\Free**

Answer (score 0):

Your `store->order status` pending and processing State Code And Title is something like this.

[image]

Comment: It is same as in the above screenshot.